# Opencart. Как узнать версию php?

Tags: php, opencart

Привет!

Сейчас работаю над сайтом на cms opencart, ocstore 2.1.0.2.1. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что возникают постоянные ошибки, лог-файл растёт как на дрожжах, есть подозрения что сервер работает не на той версии php, на которой написана версия opencart. Ведь в новых версиях php постепенно убирают старые функции, их модифицируют и в некоторых случаях переименовывают.

Как узнать по версии opencart, под какую версию php он(движок, opencart) был написан?

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Да, но так я узнаю на какой версии php работает сервер, а мне нужно узнать под какую версию php написана конкретная версия opencart? Дабы не было ошибок версии должны совпадать

Comment: никак не узнать... можно лишь прикинуть...... `Для 2.0 - 2.1 - 2.2 нужен PHP 5.3 и выше, для 2.3 - PHP 5.4 и выше.` - делай выводы

Comment: А что будет если  например поставить php 7?

Comment: ну что-то отвалится наверняка, но починить можно

Comment: Так посмотрите что валится в лог. Ворнинги? Какая-то функция depricated? Смотрите, с какой версии она depricated. Или может не в версии проблема, а в том, что уровень лог ошибок выкручен на максимум, и валятся нотисы? Текущую версию PHP и лог ошибок в студию! И уровень лог ошибок `var_dump(error_reporting());` также покажите

Comment: вот блин, некропост!

Answer (score 1):

Коробочный (чистый и с базовым набором модулей) OC2.x (да и 3.х) минимально просит php5.4, он же под php7 работает без проблем. Но это не очевидно для кастомных сборок, тем, модулей и расширений, ибо там действует комьюнити.
И ваааааще, ходите иногда на [opencart.com](https://www.opencart.com) если педалите магазины на опенкарте =)

Answer (score 0):

В корневой папке сайта нужно создать файл info.php с таким содержанием:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Затем в адресной строке браузера открыть данный файл `domen.com/info.php`